# How do I find what the Eclipse Cross Settings Prefix should be?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have installed the latest version of Eclipse on my Windows 7 64-bit machine and the mingw compiler. In setting up a Hello World project, all goes well until I am asked for the Cross Settings what the Prefix is and the Path. The Path is obvious, it's the path to the compiler. However, I haven't the slightest idea what the Prefix is and Googling for much of the day hasn't enlightened me other than finding that a lot of other people have asked the question. Unfortunately the answers I've found appear to be for specific hardware. All I want to do is to produce an executable that will run on a Windows 32 bit or 64 bit machine.

So, what is the Prefix and how do I find what it should be?

Comment: Can you possibly post a screenshot of where you are asked for this information? It may help me improve my answer and make it more relevant.

Answer (score 3):

What is probably happening here is that CDT is not locating your MingW or GCC installations.

### simple - but unlikely reason - covering bases

There can be many reasons, from the simple - but unlikely at this point:

1. You don't have mingw installed
2. You don't have GCC installed

This can be tested easily by starting a shell and running `gcc --version`.

### CDT heuristic not working

To more complicated reasons relating to your installation not being detected because the heuristic in CDT did not work on your machine. To find the correct settings, CDT will do:

1. Check `$MINGW_HOME/bin` for existence
2. Check `<Eclipse install location>/mingw/bin` for existence
3. Look for `mingw32-gcc.exe` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` on the `PATH`
4. Check `C:\MinGW` for existence

If CDT cannot find any of the above, you may lead to the situation you are in.

### So, how to fix it!

### Option 1

Start Eclipse from within a mingw set up shell. i.e. the one you can successfully run `gcc --version` from. That way Eclipse will inherit an environment that can launch GCC successfully.

### Option 2

Set your environment up so that `MINGW_HOME` is properly defined. You can do this at the system level or within the build settings in Eclipse CDT. For example, on my machine in the build settings for the project (Right-click on the project, choose *Properties*, then choose *C/C++* -> *Environment*) I have set:

- `MINGW_HOME` to `C:\MinGW`
- `MSYS_HOME` to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0`
- `PATH` to `${MINGW_HOME}\bin;${MSYS_HOME}\bin;<my normal path>`

and this allows Eclipse to launch gcc as part of the build process.

**NOTE** The above setting were done automatically on my machine because mingw was correctly located by the heuristic.

Here is a screenshot of the build settings if it helps:

[image: env]

### Prefix: Under the hood

To try and answer part of your original question about what Prefix is, I provide the below information. It is unlikely to be particularly helpf

Prefix, in GCC parlance, refers to the directory under which all the related GCC files are placed. With different prefixes you can have multiple GCC installed on your machine.

From the [GCC FAQ](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple):

> It may be desirable to install multiple versions of the compiler on
>   the same system. This can be done by using different prefix paths at
>   configure time and a few symlinks.

The concept comes from autotools in general. Autotools is the standard GNU make system (where you do `./configure && make` - simplified). The prefix is the command line option to the configure stage (`--prefix`) to specify where to install the tool to. GCC above uses the --prefix to allow multiple GCCs on your system.

If you really want to know more about this, read the [autobook](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/). The section on [configuring](https://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_14.html) covers --prefix:

> ‘--prefix=prefix’
>
> The –prefix option is one of the most frequently
>   used. If generated ‘Makefile’s choose to observe the argument you pass
>   with this option, it is possible to entirely relocate the
>   architecture-independent portion of a package when it is installed.
>   For example, when installing a package like Emacs, the following
>   command line will cause the Emacs Lisp files to be installed in
>   ‘/opt/gnu/share’:
>
> ```
>   $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/gnu
> ```
>
> It is important to stress that this behavior is dependent on the generated files making use of this
>   information. For developers writing these files, Automake simplifies
>   this process a great deal. Automake is introduced in Introducing GNU
>   Automake.

Additionally, Mingw takes advantage of all this prefix options. Read more about that on [mingw's site](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/relocatablehowtoformingw). But the short of it is that the main prefix for mingw is `/mingw`.

Comment: PS If you do resolve your problem, and have some info about what is different about your setup the CDT devs would be grateful for a well formed bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-build-managed